# Fastest way to reach to surface from mine

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have read many article which shows that railway is fastest way of climbing.
Some people claim water boat elevator is fastest.
I would like to present a nice affordable method for those who have started mining. As iron is found later (for new players). I have shown the method in answer.

Answer (score 0):

The quick method for new players is shown below. But this only works for Minecraft (not Minecraft pe)

Use stairs. Ladders are quite expensive (you need to cut a lot of wood).

Build something like this

DS000DDDDDDDDDDDD
DDS000DDDDDDDDDDD
DDDS000DDDDDDDDDD
DDDDS000DDDDDDDDD
DDDDDS000DDDDDDDD

Where S is stair;
            D is dirt or stone;
            0 is air

Till the place you want.

And what you have to do is run through the stairs. I have observed that stair run is faster than redstone powered rail.
Running can be done by double tapping key 'w'.

Also while using redstone railway you need to place powered rail every 2 blocks. (Very expensive for new players).

Comment: Its a nice clean answer although i doubt that its faster then the boat elevator.

Comment: Also making stairs can be time consuming also. IMO I would just remove the stairs and jump.

Comment: The fastest is minecart elevator (minecarts spaced 4 blocks apart vertically, clicking from one to the next). Stairs are pretty quick, but take a lot of horizontal space. Furthermore, there's a dedicated key for sprinting now, so you don't have to double-tap w.